# Angular - Circular dependency found when using ngNotificationsBar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I try to use [ng-notifications-bar](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/ng-notifications-bar) module, I have code like this:

```
angular.module('app', [
    uiRouter,
    Common.name,
    Components.name,
    angularMaterial,
    'ngTable',
    'gridster',
    'ngNotificationsBar'
  ])
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', ['notifications', function(notifications) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      notifications.showError({message: exception});
    };
  }]);
```

but got error:

> [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- notifications <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $timeout <- $$rAF <- $mdGesture

I've tried to modify the library to use `$injector` to get $timeout and $rootScope but that didn't help also tried to use `$injector` to get `notifications` in `$exceptionHandler` factory but got the same error.

Comment: What does your `$injector` attempt look like?

Comment: @MattWay `var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');` or `var notifications = $injector.get('notifications');`

Comment: do you call `get()` inside or outside the returned function?

Comment: @MattWay outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty poor design from angular it looks on this one. You can't inject `$rootScope` in any form into `$exceptionHandler` due to the dependency.

You can use `$injector` to get around these kinds of (out-of-your-hands) dependency problems, you just need to make sure that the injected module is used inside the return function to ensure that at the time of calling `.get()` the dependent module has actually loaded. For example:

```
// won't not be available here
var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

return function(exception, cause) {
  // will be available here
  var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
};
```

This is because `$injector` is used to grab the dependency at run time.

Comment: I've used `var notifications = $injector.get('notifications');` in that function insidead so I don't need to modify the library where `$rootScope` is used.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice clean object-oriented design to avoid circular dependencies: use the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Create a generic service to which you can attach handlers, and set it up from a `run` block. Basically all the other solutions suggest something similar, but with using global variables outside of angular, or bypassing the automatic dependency injection.

```js
angular.module("App", [])
.factory("notifications", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.notifications = [];
  function showMessage(msg) {
    $rootScope.notifications.push(msg);
  }
  return { showMessage };
})
.factory("$exceptionHandler", function(MyExceptionService) {
  return function(e, cause) {
    MyExceptionService.fire(e, cause);
  };
})
.factory("MyExceptionService", function() {
  const handlers = [];
  return {
    addHandler(h) { handlers.push(h); },
    fire(e, cause) { handlers.forEach(h => { h(e, cause); }) }
  };
})
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.clicked = () => {
    throw new Error("Error made");
  };
})
.run(function(MyExceptionService, notifications) {
  MyExceptionService.addHandler(err => {
    notifications.showMessage({ message: err.message });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clicked()">Make Error</button>
  <div>Errors:</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in notifications">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

For comparison, here is the wrong one (with the circular dependency):

```js
angular.module("App", [])
.factory("notifications", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.notifications = [];
  function showMessage(msg) {
    $rootScope.notifications.push(msg);
  }
  return { showMessage };
})
.factory("$exceptionHandler", function(notifications) {
  return function(e, cause) {
    notifications.showMessage({ message: err.message });
  };
})
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.clicked = () => {
    throw new Error("Error made");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clicked()">Make Error</button>
  <div>Errors:</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in notifications">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```